# How to understand whether this isn't normally distributed or not?

Tags: statistics

One hour carbon monoxide concentrations in air samples from a large city average 12 ppm and with standard deviation 9 ppm.

I have no idea how to end up with a conclusion. I only thought of using that in a normally distributed random variable median=mean however couldn't apply it here in any way. Any tips?

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Comment: It's in the topic.

Comment: It's implied by the context, I think. Median has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: WHat's the actual question  about carbon monoxide levels you are required to answer using the normality assumption?

Answer (score 0):

If the only issue is whether to assume the data are normal, I'd vote against
normality.

Unnecessarily strictly speaking, a normal distribution should not be used
to model any kind of measurement that cannot take negative values. However,
heights and most test scores can't be negative, and the normal distribution
is widely used to model both.

The issue of negative values is avoided
because 0 is many standard deviations away for the mean. For example, with
heights of adult men (in inches), heights might have $\mu \approx 69$ with $\sigma
\approx 4.$ Under the normal assumption, essentially all heights would
within $\mu \pm 5\sigma$ or $69 \pm 20$, an interval that gets nowhere near 0.
So 'theoretical' negative values would be so unlikely that we can just
ignore the possibility.

However, for your CO measurements with $\mu = 12$ and $\sigma = 9$
a normal distribution does not seem feasible. One would have about
9% negative values, as computed in R statistical software. This seems
an unrealistic model.

```
pnorm(0, 12, 9)
## 0.09121122
```